# How do I use a specific font in a message box?

Tags: delphi

How to use a specific font name and its size in a Delphi 7's procedure, like below :

```
procedure TForm1.infoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(
  '- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'+chr(10)+
  '- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'+chr(10)+
  '- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
  );
end;
```

Comment: `ShowMessage` uses system font and I doubt that you can alter it without system wide changes

Comment: You can create a form, put a label on it, set the label's font and size.  When you want to show your message, do a ShowModal on that form.

Comment: The easy-way use a custom form to display the message; the hard-way : capture the Handle of the Windows dialog using a `CBT` hook , then check for the `HCBT_ACTIVATE` code and finally use the `WM_SETFONT` message to change the font.

Comment: @RRUZ I knew that was possible and wanted to say it but wasn't sure of the actual nature, and I wasn't ready to start learning about all that :-)

Comment: Certainly. Create your own form, put a label on it, and assign that label any font and style you want. You can even use multiple labels and give each one a different font and style. Once you've created it, use `ShowModal` to present it to the user. You can even create your own procedure to do so, naming it `ShowMessageMyWay` or something else inventive if you'd like.

Comment: PS - Why use `chr(10)` when you can use `sLineBreak`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `Dialogs` unit there is function `CreateMessageDialog: TForm` used in the `MessageDlg` function to create message form. You can use it with some customization before form showing:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  with CreateMessageDialog('- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', mtInformation, [mbOk], mbOk) do
  try
    // Sets font for whole form including buttons
    {
    Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
    Font.Size := 12;
    }
    // Sets font for label(s) only
    for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
      if Controls[i] is TLabel then
        with Controls[i] as TLabel do
        begin
          Font.Name := 'Times New Roman';
          Font.Size := 12;
        end;
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own form and style it however you need:

1. Create a custom TForm
2. Put a label and/or other elements on it, and assign them any font and style you want.
3. Create a function that will rig the form and display it with `ShowModal` to the user.

Comment: Copy-past of the @KenWhite comment. Personally I prefer to hint for askers in comments instead of completely answers. Have luck!

Comment: @Abelisto: now stop and think about it, did you downvote an answer or the person?

Comment: aaa  @KromStern In case if some comment about the question makes the answer to it - Asker can write the answer and vote it as the solution. Personally I think it is the perfect practice. You are copying text from the not your comments to the answer. As I can see, "Krom Stern" is not "RzV" Good luck.

Comment: @Abelisto: You've been around for a while now and you have probably noticed the trend from some of the high-rep Delphi guys here, who post answers in comments and walk away. If they consistently choose to write comments instead of answers that's up to them. Questions are there to be answered. Right?

Comment: @Abelisto: I have deleted my c/p answer and wrote a new one from scratch. Now you say that if an answer to 2+2=? was given in comments then no one can post a 4 as an answer? If the answer is violating SO rules please flag it for moderator attention. If the answer is misleading - downvote it and add a comment.

Comment: @Abelisto: Even if that was c/p content - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user

Comment: aaa @KromStern Have fun again. I am not (absolutely not) the fun of the copyrights. Software must be open-source and so on. In the other case I absolutely respect the work of others. And if somebody make the work that useful for others - it work must be at least thankful. Dixi.

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be changing the used default font.

```
aOldFontName := Screen.MessageFont.Name;
Screen.MessageFont.Name := 'Courier New';
with CreateMessageDialog(aLines, mtInformation, [mbOk], mbOk) do
try
  Screen.MessageFont.Name := aOldFontName;
  ShowModal;
finally
  Free;
end;
```