# Delphi 7 change the font size of message box content

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-7

I am using below code which satisfy my requirement to show message in Hindi(other than English) language for a desktop application, but the displayed message's font size is quite small. The code is as below-

```
line: UTF8String;

MessageBoxW(0,pwidechar(UTF8decode(line)),pwidechar(UTF8decode(line)),0);
```

From where it does pick the font size and what will I need to additionally add to change the font size?
I followed the thread "How do I use a specific font in a message box?" but the problem is to use the utf8string (in Hindi) on that form to display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a specific font in a message box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859367/how-do-i-use-a-specific-font-in-a-message-box)

Comment: It's a system dialog. The user gets to choose.

Comment: What do you mean by "user gets to choose"

Comment: The user can change font preferences within Windows. Those are the settings used. Have you looked at the link in the first comment?

Comment: The label shows number of question marks instead of Hindi text

Comment: You're using Delphi 7 which was pre-unicode enforcement.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to explain with the word pre unicode enforcement

Comment: Google "Delphi Unicode" - it does a much better job of explaining than I ever can.

Comment: @PrateekShukla The question marks indicate that you've messed up the text encoding somehow. And yes, the user is in charge of the font size in the message dialog.

Comment: @David Exactly why I mentioned that, but we can't see the code OP is using so I can only guess.

Comment: Surely the font size is the same as the one used in the message boxes displayed by all the other programs on your computer. If the text is too small, then adjust your system font size so you can read it. All programs will benefit from your change, not just your program. Assume that your users will have similar settings on their own computers.

Comment: @Rob it will not be feasible to change font size on every client's desktop.

Comment: Is it possible to change fonts of computer system programatically

Comment: That's not what I suggested. *Do not* consider changing your customers' settings. I suggested changing *your* settings so that *you* can read your text. I suggested you assume that your customers will have already made similar changes to their settings so they can read the text of all their other Hindi programs. Your program will benefit from their prior effort.

Comment: Otherwise, do not use `MessageBox()` at all.  Create your own `TForm` and use whatever font settings you want on it.

Comment: @Prateek do you have the same problem with all programs on your machine?

Comment: @RemyLebeau D7 - no unicode.  Getting Devanagari code page (57002) to work properly is a nightmare.

Comment: @J... `MessageBoxW` supports Unicode

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, but that brings us back to the original question...

Comment: @J...: for pre-D2009 versions, there is always the old TNT components for handing Unicode in the UI.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which I indicated in my answer, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The font and font size used for system dialog boxes is set globally in Windows by the user (this dialog is accessed in various different ways in different versions of Windows).

[image]

You cannot (or, rather, really really *should not*) change this setting programmatically since it does not just affect your application but *all* applications that run on the system for that user.

Displaying a custom dialog box is an option, per [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29859367/327083) but since you are using Delphi 7 the VCL does not natively support Unicode strings for any of its visual components.  You would need to look into either using a set of third-party Unicode-aware VCL components (TNT Controls are still available free, unsupported, if you look) or, alternatively, design new ones yourself.  The former option is naturally the most sensible.

Comment: I would suggest using a unicode version of `DrawText` or similar.